# How to find if the means of multiple groups are significantly different when the data is of non-normal distribution: Kruskal-Wallis?

Tags: r, anova, mean, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I have dive data from ten shark tags. The tags recorded depth every 10 seconds while at liberty and returned a combined total of >900 k depth records. I would like to see if there is a significant difference in the mean dive depth depending on the size of the shark. There are five size categories. Ideally, I would like to apply a 1-way ANOVA, however, `ad.test()` indicates that the dive data is on a non-normal distribution (the sample size is too large to test via `shapiro.test()`). I attempted to log(y+1) transform the data (results below) but it still failed `ad.test()`. 
[image]

I read that a Kruskal-Wallis test is a non-parametric alternative to a 1-way ANOVA, e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143959/how-to-test-if-2-means-are-significantly-different-for-non-normal-non-paired-dat) which should be followed by post-hoc analysis. However, although sources recommend a Kruskal-Wallis test as a non-parametric alternative, they also say that it tests the median rather than the mean, e.g. [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/parametric-and-non-parametric-data/). Am I using an incorrect test? If so, how can I find out if there is a significant difference between the mean dive depths for each shark size category when my dive data is of a non-normal distribution?

For reference, I have included the script below.

```
Depth<-mydata$Depth
Size<-factor(mydata$Size)

library(lattice)
kruskal.test(Depth,Size)

library(pgirmess) # ad-hoc
kruskalmc(Depth ~ Size, probs = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing numerical and graphical descriptions of dive depths it is difficult to give advice with confidence it is relevant. If you have over 500,000 observations and five categories, then I suppose there must be
tens of thousands of dive depth observations per group.

This makes it tempting to suppose that your group means will be roughly normal [see note below],
so that an ANOVA would give useful results.

**Equal variances?** In these circumstances I would worry whether group variances might be grossly unequal. Even with large numbers of replications in each group, this would invalidate a *standard* ANOVA. Also, an assumption of the original K-W test is that group populations have the 'same shape', which implies equal variances. (Maybe some
recent implementations of K-W allow for relaxing this assumption, but you would need to investigate that.)

**ANOVA procedure that does not assume equal variances.** Thus, I would use the
version of a one-way ANOVA implemented in the R procedure
`oneway.test`, which does not assume equal variances. (The
approach to correcting for unequal variances is similar to that
used in the Welch two-sample t test, but extended to $g > 2$ groups.)

**Simulated example with exponential data:** If your data were exponential, I suppose you would have found
a helpful transformation, but I will use exponential data in
an exploratory simulation below: In R, exponential distributions are parameterized by the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rexp(10^5, 1/10)
x2 = rexp(10^5, 1/10)
x3 = rexp(10^5, 1/15)
x4 = rexp(10^5, 1/15)
x5 = rexp(10^5, 1/20)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
g = as.factor(rep(1:5, each=10^5))
```

Boxplots give an overview of the data. The red `X`'s show the five
group means.

```
boxplot(x ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
 a = rowMeans(rbind(x1,x2,x2,x4,x5))
 points(1:5, a, pch="X", col="red")
```

[image]

The ANOVA (not assuming equal variances), finds highly significant
differences among group means--with a P-value very near $0.$

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

     One-way analysis of means 
   (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 7913.5, num df = 4, denom df = 246160, 
  p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Notice that in a standard ANOVA `denom df` would be
$5(100\,000 - 1)$ which is much greater than $246\,160$ above. This decrease in denominator DF is a 'correction' for grossly different group variances inherited from
grossly different population variances $(\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = 100,\,$ $\sigma_3^2 = \sigma_4^2 = 225,\,$ $\sigma_5^2 = 400).$

***Ad hoc* comparisons.** We can use Welch 2-sample t tests (also without assuming equal group variances) for *ad hoc* comparisons. Use Bonferroni or some other
method to guard against false discovery.

Knowing how the data were
simulated, we would hope to find a significant difference between
Groups 2 and 3 $(\mu_2 = 10 \ne \mu_3 = 15),$ but not between Groups 1 and 2 $(\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 10).$ In the first *ad hoc* comparison we do find a highly significant difference between
means of Groups 2 and 3:

```
t.test(x2, x3)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x2 and x3
t = -88.042, df = 174060, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
...
```

Only the non-significant P-value $0.775 > 0.05$ is shown for
the second *ad hoc* comparison:

```
t.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.7745113
```

*Note:* Means of sample of size $n=100,000$ from exponential distributions with mean $1/\lambda = \mu = 15$ are distributed as $\mathsf{Gamma}(n, n/\lambda)$ [black curve], which is very nearly $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma=15/\sqrt{n})$ [red dashes].

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, however, it was my understanding that I cannot apply the suggested method as my data is of a non-normal distribution?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but the crux of my Answer is that your understanding is not correct.

Comment: Following your comment, I came across the `oneway` function in the `userfriendlyscience` package. The following code provided a simple way to apply the suggested ANOVA and post hoc test at the same time `oneway(x, y, levene=TRUE, corrections = TRUE, posthoc = 'bonferroni',  ...)` which though might be helpful for others in future.